# Is it possible to debug an obfuscated Android app?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, obfuscation

Suppose I have the code and the mapping of the obfuscated app. Can I somehow debug this app within Eclipse?

Comment: Define what you mean by "debug" in this case.

Comment: Eclipse has a debug mode , which lets you have breakpoints , show&edit the values of variables , ... I want to be able to use this mode even on my obfuscated app , provided that i have the code and the mapping .

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, Proguard obfuscation is activated only when the app is exported, aka Release Mode.

Debug information are not added in this configuration, as far as I know.

> When you build your application in release mode, either by running ant
>   release or by using the Export Wizard in Eclipse, the build system
>   automatically checks to see if the proguard.config property is set. If
>   it is, ProGuard automatically processes the application's bytecode
>   before packaging everything into an .apk file. Building in debug mode
>   does not invoke ProGuard, because it makes debugging more cumbersome.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#enabling)

**Edit:**

It looks some like hackish solutions exist.
Here are two discussions that may help you:

- [Issue 14469: Optional ability to run proguard on debug builds when using Eclipse ADT](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14469)
- [Issue 34019: Allow proguard stripping in debug builds from ADT](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34019)

Comment: This I know . The question is , if I can still somehow debug the obfuscated app .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Proguard simply makes it difficult to make sense of it by obfuscating the code.

Comment: Really ? How do i achieve it?